# indexing fails in svmono

Tags: indexing, sv-classes

Buildign the code below (pdflatex, makeindex, pdflatex) causes an error

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment multicols undefined.
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\index{foo}Text

\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}
```

I can of course make the error go away using `\usepackage{multicol}` (and shall note this in an answer below), but I'd like to understand what's happening: has svmono simply failed to declare a dependency?

Comment: If you change to `\usepackage{imakeidx}` the index will be built automatically (and `multicol` loaded). But in case you're submitting the paper, this may be a problem, if the publisher has an old TeX distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svmono.cls` contains the lines

```
\if@threecolind
                   \begin{multicols}{3}[\chapter*{\indexname}%
                \else
                   \begin{multicols}{2}[\chapter*{\indexname}%
                \fi
```

in the "begin" part of the definition of the `index` environment. As you can see, the index will be built using the `multicols` environment and this requires the `multicol` package.

The documentation for `svmono` mentions that both the `makeidx` and `multicol` packages are required to build an index, so you need to load both packages.

Comment: So it's missing a `\RequirePackage`?

Comment: @Mohan I don't think it's missing (see the final remark in my updated answer). In the same way that the class doesn't internally loads `makeidx`, and leave it to the user, it also doesn't load `multicol` and the user has to do it.